# Android localized app doesn't display some polish characters from my strings.xml properly

Tags: android, localization, polish

OK, so i have localized resources in resources-pl as per googles documentation. My problem is that some characters seem to work, and some not.

I've scoured the interwebs, but from what i can see it SHOULD work so long as the file is UTF-8 encoded, but for some characters, i get the classic square icon instead, for example on HTC One and nexus 5.

The strange thing is that i just tried on an old Samsung Galaxy S, and there the 'weird' characters do show up, but in bold!

Example of offending string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="action_nearestLocation">Najbliższą lokalizacje</string>
```

The 'z' and last 'a' in 'Nabli...' both show up as squares in my button. I set the text like this:

```
button.setText(R.string.action_nearestLocation);
```

I've re-saved the file in Ultraedit to make sure it's UTF-8. I'm out of ideas, anybody with one please speak up :)

Oh, and final point - i'm hoping not having to muck around with unicode-numbers.

Comment: Maybe you're using a custom font and that's causing the problem? BTW, there is an error in your string. It should be "lokalizację" :-)

Comment: Make it an answer and i'll give you a nice checkbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you're using a custom font that doesn't support Polish characters. Also, there is an error in your string: it should be "lokalizację" :-)

Comment: Gah!! Thank you, that was it. I've abstracted the font handling into custom button and textfield classes due to the memory leak issue (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904), so i forgot about it. Cheers! And thanks for the typo heads up! The reason it works on some phones i suppose is because that the Samsung one has some "fallback to default font" mechanism that the others phones do not.